# SSH Tunnel (Local Port Forwarding) fails because of Docker

Tags: ssh, docker, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to enable local port forwarding between my local machine and a remote vm. Inside of this vm runs a docker container which exposes port 7070. Essentially I want everything that happens on that exposed port, to be relayed to my local machine via ssh-tunnel.

```bash
$ docker ps
> PORTS
> 0.0.0.0:7070->7070/tcp, :::7070->7070/tcp
```

i then from my local machine execute

```bash
$ ssh -N -f user@destination_ip -L localhost:7070:localhost:7070 -v
```

which after authentication returns this:

```
debug1: Local connections to localhost:7070 forwarded to remote address localhost:7070
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 7070.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 7070.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
```

Trying

```bash
$ curl localhost:7070
```

on my **local machine** returns

```
debug1: Connection to port 7070 forwarding to localhost port 7070 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

while on the **remote machine** it returns

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

On the remote machine trying to determine what blocks port 7070 with

```bash
$ sudo netstat -plant  | grep 7070
```

returns

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7070            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14231/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::7070                 :::*                    LISTEN      14238/docker-proxy
```

I am running centos 7 remotely if that is important

Comment: `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` would suggest that  `docker-proxy` is refusing the connection

Comment: how would i fix that?

Comment: by checking why your *mystery* (to us anyway) docker container is doing that